# What is the right way to reference EntityObject from Core 3.1 and Standard 2.0

Tags: c#

I need to reference a legacy Framework 4.6.1 project from a Standard 2.0 class library project and a Core 3.1 test project.

Both projects work just fine, until I touch an `EntityObject`, which gives a compilation error `CS0012 The type 'EntityObject' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced`.

I have tried installing numerous versions of Entity Framework in different projects, but nothing changes this behaviour.

I can fix the compilation error by adding a reference to `System.Data.Entity.dll` in the `.NETFramework\v4.6.1` folder, and succesfully run my code.

However, not only does this feel like a totally wrong way of fixing this, but also, my Core 3.1 tests won't run, throwing `Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution` exceptions.

So, my questions is: What is the right way to reference EntityObject from Core 3.1 and Standard 2.0?*

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.dataclasses.entityobject?view=netframework-4.8#moniker-applies-to As you can see it is only supported by .NET Framework families. That is impossible.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go and push the EntityObject behind an interface, which is more futureproof anyways, but I keep wondering why the code does run when referencing the dll itself.